# Move/copy a file into 2+ destination folders if there is a delimitator in the filename

Tags: excel, vba, windows, excel-2010

I want to expand this vba script that moves files from an inbox folder to the correct destination folder by using variables from the filename to lookup the correct investment folder path for the file in Sharepoint and then subsequently moves the file to the destination folder. Currently, the vba script only works on a 1:1 ratio though, moving 1 document into 1 destination folder. I need it to also be able to move 1 document into multiple destination folders if needed [or rather, move the document into the 1 destination folder then save copies of it to any others]. The trigger would be the existence of a special delimiter in the filename separating destinations. That said, it would also be helpful if the original filename was updated to include only the investment name for each copy saved. For Example -

```
Filename: 12901-01_Upside III_Carnegie;Carrington_CAS_2023.03.30.pdf

Action 1: Move original file into the Carnegie investment folder and rename:  12901-01_Upside III_Carnegie \_CAS_2023.03.30.pdf

Action 2: Save a copy of original file into the Carrington investment folder and rename: 12901-01_Upside III_Carrington_CAS_2023.03.30.pdf
```

There are few other nuances being considered in the full code, which you can see more pieces of in the screenshot below, but my main question is how to move a document multiple places if there is a delimitator in the filename. So, please keep in mind that I have only copied the sections of code below that I think are relevant to this question.

[image]

[image]

```
Public TaxPath_12900 As String 
Public Investments As New collection
Public LogDataCol As New collection
Public LogDataBool As Boolean
Public ClientCode As String
Public ClientFolder As String
Public FieldCountAdj As Integer
Public ClientMapsFolder As String
Public ClientLogFolder As String
Public StopFlag As Boolean

Function CheckBoxFileExists(ByVal filePath As String) As Boolean
‘checks if file exists by searching for the filename in the folder and returns “true” or “false”
    CheckBoxFileExists = False
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
    For i = 0 To 4 'wait for 5 seconds total if needed
        If fso.FileExists(filePath) = False Then
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Else
            CheckBoxFileExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Sub SetClientCodeVar()

    Select Case ClientCode
        Case "12900" 
            ClientFolder = " C:\Box\Client II\12901 Fund\Acct\Client Document Inbox\”
            ClientMapsFolder = "C:\Box\Client II\12901 Fund\Acct\Client Maps\ " 
            ClientLogFolder = "C:\Box\Client II\12901 Fund\Acct\Client Log (SharePoint Upload)\"
            FieldCountAdj = 1 
            TaxPath_12900 = " C:\Box\Client II\12901 Fund\Tax\Shared\tax docs\downloaded docs\”
    End Select
End Sub
Function PopulateListBoxFromCSV(ListBox As MSForms.ListBox, clientName As String)
'needs "ms scripting runtime" and "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

    ClientCode = Mid(clientName, 2, InStr(clientName, "]") - 2)
    Call SetClientCodeVar
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = ClientMapsFolder & ClientCode & "_MAP.CSV"
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim row As Long
    Dim arrData() As String
    'open the file
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, ForReading)
    UserForm1.Label_RefreshTime.Caption = "Mapping Refresh: " & FileDateTime(filePath)
    'Open the file
    'Open filePath For Input As #1
    ' Read the data from the file
    Dim line As String
    Dim rowString As String
    Dim dupeRecords As Boolean
    dupeRecords = False
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
        row = row + 1
        rowString = ts.ReadLine
        line = ReplaceCSVDelimiter(rowString)  
        arrData = Split(line, "|")
        'populate collection
        Dim investment As clsInvestmentList
        Set investment = New clsInvestmentList
        If ItemExists(arrData(0) & "-" & arrData(2), Investments) = False Then
            investment.RowNum = row
            investment.fundID = UCase(arrData(0))
            investment.FundName = arrData(1)
            investment.InvestmentID = UCase(arrData(2))
            investment.InvestmentName = arrData(3)
            investment.ProjectID = arrData(4)
            investment.BaseFolderPath = arrData(5)
            investment.StatementFolders = arrData(6)
            investment.InvestActivityFolders = arrData(7)
            Investments.Add investment, arrData(0) & "-" & arrData(2)
        Else
            dupeRecords = True
        End If
    Loop
    Call PopulateListBox(ListBox)
    ts.Close
    If dupeRecords = True Then MsgBox ("Note: Your sharepoint list contains duplicate records for the same Fund ID & Investment ID pairing. Please remove duplicate records from sharepoint " & ClientCode & "_MAP.")
End Function
Function PopulateListBox(ListBox As MSForms.ListBox, Optional filterFundID As String = "")

    Dim item As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    For Each item In Investments
        If filterFundID <> "" Then
            If filterFundID <> item.fundID Then
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
        End If
            ' Add the data to the list box
            ListBox.AddItem item.RowNum
            ListBox.List(i, 1) = item.fundID
            ListBox.List(i, 2) = item.FundName
            ListBox.List(i, 3) = item.InvestmentID
            ListBox.List(i, 4) = item.InvestmentName
            ListBox.List(i, 5) = item.ProjectID
            i = i + 1
NextIteration:
    Next item
End Function
Sub ExportDiagnostics()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As Variant
    filePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Folder Diagnostics " & ClientCode, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Select Destination Folder")
    If filePath = False Then Exit Sub
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim UFLB As MSForms.ListBox
    Set UFLB = UserForm2.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To UFLB.ListCount - 1
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).value = UFLB.List(i, 0)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).value = UFLB.List(i, 1)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 3).value = UFLB.List(i, 2)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 4).value = UFLB.List(i, 3)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 5).value = UFLB.List(i, 4)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 6).value = UFLB.List(i, 5)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 7).value = UFLB.List(i, 8)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 8).value = UFLB.List(i, 6)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 9).value = UFLB.List(i, 7)
    Next i
    Call ResizeSheet(ws)
    wb.SaveAs filePath
    wb.Close
    MsgBox ("List exported to Excel.")
End Sub
Function CreateBrowserFormPath() As collection

    Dim tempCollection As New collection
    Dim str As String
    Dim itemNo As Integer
    Dim UF As UserForm
    Set UF = UserForm1
    itemNo = Int(UF.ListBox1.List(UF.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0))
    str = Investments.item(itemNo).BaseFolderPath
    If Right(str, 1) <> "\" Then str = str & "\"
        tempCollection.Add str
        Select Case UF.ComboBox1.Text
            Case "FS & PCAPs"
                str = str & Investments.item(Int(itemNo)).StatementFolders & "\"
                If UF.ComboBox2.Text <> "" Then
                    str = str & UF.ComboBox2.Text & "\"
                    If UF.ComboBox3.Text <> "" Then str = str & UF.ComboBox3.Text & "\"
                End If
            Case "Investment Activity"
                str = str & Investments.item(itemNo).InvestActivityFolders & "\"
        End Select
    tempCollection.Add str
    Set CreateBrowserFormPath = tempCollection
End Function

Function GetFileMetaData(UFLB As MSForms.ListBox, Optional filterFundID As String = "")

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ClientFolder)
    If CheckBoxFolderExists(ClientFolder) = False Then Exit Function
    Dim fileNameArr() As String
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim item As String
    Dim sType As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim charCount As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(oFile.Name, 4)) <> ".pdf" Then GoTo NextIteration
        fileNameArr = Split(Replace(LCase(oFile.Name), ".pdf", ""), "_")
        If filterFundID <> "" Then
            If filterFundID <> UCase(fileNameArr(0)) Then
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
        End If
        charCount = Len(oFile.Name) - Len(Replace(oFile.Name, "_", ""))
        If charCount <> 3 + FieldCountAdj Then GoTo NextIteration
        UFLB.AddItem oFile.Name
     ' we want to use the investment ID variable below to retrieve Fund Name / Fund ID from our "investments" collection
        UFLB.List(i, 1) = oFile.DateLastModified
        If ItemExists(fileNameArr(0) & "-" & fileNameArr(1), Investments) = False Then
                UFLB.List(i, 2) = ""
                UFLB.List(i, 3) = ""
                UFLB.List(i, 4) = ""
                UFLB.List(i, 5) = ""
                UFLB.List(i, 6) = ""
                UFLB.List(i, 7) = ""
            i = i + 1
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        UFLB.List(i, 2) = UCase(fileNameArr(0))
        UFLB.List(i, 3) = Investments.item(fileNameArr(0) & "-" & fileNameArr(1)).FundName
        UFLB.List(i, 4) = UCase(fileNameArr(1))
        UFLB.List(i, 5) = Investments.item(fileNameArr(0) & "-" & fileNameArr(1)).InvestmentName
        Select Case UCase(fileNameArr(2 + FieldCountAdj))
            Case "CAS"
                sType = "Capital Account Statement"
            Case "FS"
                sType = "Financial Statements"
            Case "CD"
                sType = "Distribution"
            Case "CC"
                sType = "Contribution"
            Case "K-1"
                sType = "Tax"
        End Select
        UFLB.List(i, 6) = sType
        UFLB.List(i, 7) = ConvertDateFormat(fileNameArr(3 + FieldCountAdj))
On Error GoTo 0
    i = i + 1
NextIteration:
    Next oFile
End Function
Function ItemExists(ByRef value As Variant, ByRef collection As collection) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    ItemExists = False
    ItemExists = Not (collection.item(value) Is Nothing)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function CreateFormPath() As Collection
'function returns a collection object
    Dim tempCollection As New Collection 'Declares a variable named "tempCollection" to hold a new instance of the Collection object
    Dim strBase As String
    Dim strDocType As String
    Dim strYear As String
    Dim strQtr As String  'Declares variables to hold different parts of the path
    Dim itemKey As String  'Declares a variable named "itemKey" to hold a string
    Dim UF As UserForm  'Declares a variable named "UF" to hold a reference to a UserForm
    Set UF = UserForm3  'Assigns the reference of "UserForm3" to the "UF" variable
    itemKey = UF.ListBox1.List(UF.ListBox1.ListIndex, 2) & "-" & UF.ListBox1.List(UF.ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
    'Constructs the "itemKey" by concatenating two values from ListBox1 on the UserForm
    If ItemExists(itemKey, Investments) = False Then 'Checks if "itemKey" doesnt exist in the "Investments" collection
        tempCollection.Add ""
        tempCollection.Add ""
        tempCollection.Add ""
        tempCollection.Add ""   'Adds four empty strings to the "tempCollection"
        Set CreateFormPath = tempCollection 'Sets the function's return value to the "tempCollection".
        Exit Function
    End If
    strBase = Investments.Item(itemKey).BaseFolderPath 'Gets "BaseFolderPath" from "Investments" collection using the "itemKey"
    Dim tempDates
    tempDates = EndOfQuarter(CDate(UF.ListBox1.List(UF.ListBox1.ListIndex, 7)))
    'Retrieves a date value from ListBox1 on the UserForm and calculates the end of the quarter using the "EndOfQuarter" function
    If Right(strBase, 1) <> "\" Then strBase = strBase & "\" 'Checks if "strBase" doesn't end with a \ & adds one if needed
    Select Case UF.ListBox1.List(UF.ListBox1.ListIndex, 6) 'begins case stmt based on value in UserForm ListBox1
        Case "Capital Account Statement", "Financial Statements"'If ListBox1 value is "Capital Account Statement" or "Financial Statements", execute code block:
            tempCollection.Add "CASFS"  'Adds "CASFS" to the "tempCollection"
            strDocType = Investments.Item(itemKey).StatementFolders & "\"
            'Appends the "StatementFolders" property from the "Investments" collection to "strDocType"
            strYear = Left(tempDates, 4) & "\" 'Retrieves leftmost 4 characters of "tempDates" and appends a \ to "strYear"
            strQtr = Right(tempDates, 2) & "\" 'Retrieves rightmost 2 characters of "tempDates" and appends a \ to "strQtr"
        Case "Distribution", "Contribution" 'If ListBox1 value is "Distribution" or "Contribution", execute code block:
            tempCollection.Add "CF"  'Adds "CF" to the "tempCollection"
            strDocType = Investments.Item(itemKey).InvestActivityFolders & "\"
            'Appends the "InvestActivityFolders" property from the "Investments" collection to "strDocType".
            strYear = Left(tempDates, 4) & "\" 'Retrieves leftmost 4 characters of "tempDates" and appends a \ to "strYear"
            strQtr = Right(tempDates, 2) & "\" 'Retrieves rightmost 2 characters of "tempDates" and appends a \ to "strQtr"
        Case "Tax"  'If ListBox1's selected value is "Tax", the following code block is executed
            tempCollection.Add "Tax"  ' Adds "Tax" to the "tempCollection"
            Select Case ClientCode 'Begins another Select Case statement based on the value of "ClientCode"
                Case "12900"  'If "ClientCode" is "12900", the following code block is executed
                    strBase = TaxPath_12900  'Overrides the value of "strBase" with a predefined path
            End Select
        Case ""   'If ListBox1's selected value is empty, the following code block is executed
            tempCollection.Add ""   'Adds an empty string to the "tempCollection"
    End Select
    tempCollection.Add strBase 'Adds year base to the "tempCollection"
    tempCollection.Add strDocType 'Adds year doc type to the "tempCollection"
    tempCollection.Add strYear 'Adds year string to the "tempCollection"
    tempCollection.Add strQtr  'Adds quarter string to the "tempCollection"
    Set CreateFormPath = tempCollection  'Sets the function's return value to the "tempCollection"
End Function
Function MoveClientFiles(SourceFileName As String, ByVal DestinFileName As String)

    If Right(LCase(DestinFileName), 4) <> ".pdf" Then Exit Function
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim tempVer As String
    tempStr = Left(DestinFileName, Len(DestinFileName) - 4)
    tempVer = ""
    i = 2
    Do Until CheckBoxFileExists(tempStr & tempVer & ".pdf") = False
        tempVer = "_V" & i
    Loop
    DestinFileName = tempStr & tempVer & ".pdf"
    fso.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName
    Dim UFLB As MSForms.ListBox
    Set UFLB = UserForm3.ListBox1
    'populate collection
    Dim logData As clsInvestmentList
    Set logData = New clsInvestmentList
    logData.LogTitle = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 0)
    logData.LogUserName = Application.UserName
    logData.LogTimeStamp = Now()
    logData.LogFundID = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 2)
    logData.LogFundName = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 3)
    logData.LogInvestmentID = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 4)
    logData.LogInvestmentName = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 5)
    logData.LogDestinationFolder = DestinFileName
    logData.LogStatementType = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 6)
    logData.LogStatementDate = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 7)
    logData.LogFileDateModified = UFLB.List(UFLB.ListIndex, 1)
    LogDataCol.Add logData
    MsgBox ("File moved successfully! Details added to session log.")
    UserForm3.ListBox1.RemoveItem UserForm3.ListBox1.ListIndex
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is quite lengthy and so I am giving you an example of how your 'main question' (i.e. "how to move a document multiple places if there is a delimitator in the filename") could be done rather than re-writing your code.

The following code is commented to explain what each part does, you can then update your existing code with the relevant lines (the variable names will need to be changed to match your code). Note that the code (i.e. this `Test` method) is a runnable example so you can step through the code if you want to see how it works:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim text As String
    text = "12901-01_Upside III_Carnegie;Carrington_CAS_2023.03.30.pdf"
    
    ' split the single piece of text into file names delimited by ";"
    Dim filenames As Variant
    filenames = Split(text, ";") ' assumes semi-colon is only used to delimite names and can never appear within a file name
    
    ' iterate over each file name ... this loop can happen 1 time if no ";" is present, otherwise multiple times
    Dim index As Long, doingForFirstFile As Boolean
    For index = LBound(filenames) To UBound(filenames)
        
        ' are we working on the first file name?
        doingForFirstFile = index = LBound(filenames)
        
        If doingForFirstFile Then
            Debug.Print Now, "The first file name is '" & filenames(index) & "'"
            ' put your code to process the first copy of the file here
        Else
            Debug.Print Now, "A subsequent file name is '" & filenames(index) & "'"
            ' put your code to make subsequent copies here ... as you are using FSO then you can use its .CopyFile method
        End If
        
    Next index
    
End Sub
```

For how to use the .CopyFile method of FSO, see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method) and [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198744(v=technet.10))

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Comment: Yes this helped. Quick question, was the "test" supposed to be an attached excel file? If so, how do I click on/open/find that excel file? Thanks for the help since this is my first post!

Comment: I have a few questions. First, does this grab multiple pathways from the Sharepoint collection (i.e. a pathway for each investment name between the deliminators). Second, does this rename the version of the file being moved to the first investment folder and does it also rename the version(S) of the file copies being saved to the other investment folder(s)? Lastly, where in the code would you suggest to put this and is there any code that you think should be taken out/revised?